# Animated launch screen using a GIF

Tags: swift

When my application is opened I want my animation GIF to be opened in Launchscreen. I have done this using SwiftyGif, but I want to do this in AppDelegate. I'm using it in any class right now. I want to use it on AppDelegate.

**MAINVİEW**

```
extension MainTableViewController: SwiftyGifDelegate {
    func gifDidStop(sender: UIImageView) {
        logoAnimationView.isHidden = true
    }
}

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
   let logoAnimationView = LogoAnimationView()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        logoAnimationView.logoGifImageView.startAnimatingGif()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 view.addSubview(logoAnimationView)
        logoAnimationView.pinEdgesToSuperView()
        logoAnimationView.logoGifImageView.delegate = self
}
}
```

**LOGOANIMATIONVİEW**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyGif

class LogoAnimationView: UIView {

    let logoGifImageView: UIImageView = {
        guard let gifImage = try? UIImage(gifName: "giphy.gif") else {
            return UIImageView()
        }
        return UIImageView(gifImage: gifImage, loopCount: Int(2.0))
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 246.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1)
        addSubview(logoGifImageView)
        logoGifImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        logoGifImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(250)
            make.height.equalTo(250)
            make.width.equalTo(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            make.centerX.equalTo(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width*0.5)
        }

        //logoGifImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The launch screen is a static image.

Your code doesn't actually run until your app is finished loading, so you can't do animations in your launch screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do any action on launchscreen in iOS Native Application. You can choose alternate way like after splash screen you can load animation. check below application.

- https://apps.apple.com/qa/app/qataronweb/id1444602480